# MongoDB Aggregate is very slow

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

The Admin page shows a graph of the DAU, the data generated. (Data related to statistics.) Simple figures, including graphs, were implemented using only aggregate functions without application code writing. But as the number of data went over 50,000, it started to take a very long time. (10 seconds to 50 seconds)

Administration pages usually query data by date (createdAt). $group, $addField is frequently used.

In my collection, 'write' occurs frequently more than 'read'. Three new documents are generated per second. More data will be added quickly in the future. I hesitate to create createdAt because of this problem.

If 'writing' occurs frequently like my database, do I have to request and process the request to MongoDB several times?  Or should I add indexes and optimize queries to use aggregates efficiently?

Comment: If you are using a populate query with multiple collections in mongodb, the process may be slow. It is also useful to check your indexes. Try to give them an appropriate index according to which field you are querying. In addition, the aggregate runs multiple queries together. Therefore, there may be a slowdown.

Comment: @SamiSalihİbrahimbaş There is no problem with the API of the users of the service. However, the dashboard for the operations team is quite slow, so is it okay to add an index to solve this problem? Adding indexes reduces the performance of Wrtie, so I'm worried that users might add data rather slowly.